# How to get from a string array?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

an array of server:

> Array ( [28.01.2015] => Array ( [03] => 2 [02] => 4 ) )

was converted into a string using the `json_encode`.

The result was a string:

```
{"28.01.2015":{"03":2,"02":4}}
```

How to use Javascript to convert this string into an array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn that into a JavaScript object by using `JSON.parse()`:

```
var my_object = JSON.parse('{"28.01.2015":{"03":2,"02":4}}');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JSON.parse('{"28.01.2015":{"03":2,"02":4}}');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 1):

For achieve this, you need use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

```
JSON.parse('{"28.01.2015":{"03":2,"02":4}}');
```

Or you could organize better:

```
var string = '{"28.01.2015":{"03":2,"02":4}}';
var object = JSON.parse(string);
```